SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship with ordered association
I'm trying to create a self-referencing many-to-many relationship in sqlalchemy to be able to retrieve and modify them while ensuring the correct order.
I have a table of servers, and would like to have a chain for each server, consisting of the next servers a user should connect to.
Tried the following approach.
class ServerChain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "server_chains"

    server_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("servers.id"), primary_key=True)
    chained_server_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("servers.id"))
    seq = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Server(Base):
    __tablename__ = "servers"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    address = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    port = Column(Integer)
    chain = relationship(
        "Server",
        secondary="server_chains",
        primaryjoin=(id == ServerChain.server_id),
        secondaryjoin=(id == ServerChain.chained_server_id),
        order_by=ServerChain.seq,
        collection_class=ordering_list("seq"),
        lazy="joined",
    )

I want to be able to retrieve and set Server.chain like this with automatic ordering:
server1.chain = [server2, server3]
assert server1.chain == [server2, server3]

However looks like orderding_list tries to load seq from Server and i get the following exception:
AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'seq'
